# Python my code redirect without redirect function

Tags: python, html, redirect

This code redirects to another page which is an error page but I didn't use redirect function and I want to stop it from redirecting

### Python code:

```
   @app.route("/record",methods = ['POST','GET'])
   def get_voice():
      print("record's button was clicked")
      TFIDF = tfidf.TFIDF_CLASS()
      TFIDF.choosen_Type(1,"")
      return ""
```

### html code:

```
    <form action="http://localhost:5000/record">
    <input id="record" onclick="voice_message()" type="submit" method="POST" value=' Record'>
    </form>
```

Comment: More information is required. For a start, what is the error, what have you already tried to solve it?

Comment: i tried to change the "action" of the "form" but nothing changed

Comment: Just to clarify the question, your python code does not redirect to another page: your `Form` element is what is redirecting. Please include what javascript you have for the Form's action. Have you looked at similar questions about disabling form's redirect?